# How to make a border for every column exported to excel file using maatexcel library?

Tags: php, excel, csv, laravel-excel

I want to style every column and row with border for all of my data but not specifying the specific cell range.

This is what I found on the website documentation (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html)

Firstly, make a macro

```
use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;

Sheet::macro('styleCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, array $style) {
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray($style);
});
```

And then calling out the macro function as below:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class InvoicesExport implements WithEvents
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeExport::class  => function(BeforeExport $event) {
                $event->writer->setCreator('Patrick');
            },
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

                $event->sheet->styleCells(
                    'B2:G8',
                    [
                        'borders' => [
                            'outline' => [
                                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                                'color' => ['argb' => 'FFFF0000'],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                );
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

this works fine but it only specific the certain cell range (B2:G8 in the example above), my data is dynamic and the cell range cant be specify.